# Testing to see if center of UIImageView is equal to the side of another

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cgpoint

I am having a UIImageView moving ball1 to the right using this code being run every .01 seconds

```
ball1.center = CGPointMake(ball1.center.x + 0.5, ball1.center.y)
```

When it gets to the side of another UIImageView (Named Box1) I want it to check if it is the right box color (Box changes color on clicks) and then be able to do more stuff with it. I tried to use CGPointEqualToPoint but I am not sure how to use it and this code doesn't work either.

```
if ball1.center.x = box1.center.x - 32 {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGPointEqualToPoint` but since points are `CGFloats`, [if they're not perfectly equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430020/if-with-cgpointequaltopoint-do-not-work), it will return false. I would recommend rounding the points and then comparing.

```
CGPoint ball1Center = CGPointMake(roundf(ball1.center.x), roundf(ball1.center.y));
CGPoint box1Center = CGPointMake(roundf(box1.center.x), roundf(box1.center.y));

if (CGPointEqualToPoint(ball1Center, box1Center))
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying to put a semicolon between the CGPoint and the ball1Center and the box1Center. It doesn't think they are connected.